# PC won't turn on

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting, computer-building

My new PC broke down completely yesterday. This was my first ever PC build, I installed the components myself, but I couldn't figure out the wiring/cables so I went off to a tech-guy for help. He put the wires/cables into place, we started the computer and it was ok...

When I got home I turned it on, installed Windows 8.1, updated/installed the drivers, and downloaded some games. After I played maybe half an hour of CS:GO. I was on the PC for maybe two hours when it shut down COMPLETELY. I tried to turn it back on but it wouldn't respond at all. I took off the covers and made sure everything was sitting nice and tight, and it was. I was putting it in different power holes and such, but it wouldn't turn on. Nothing was blinking on the motherboard and such. I tried the day after too, but nothing happened.

My PSU is making some kind of buzzing noise for maybe 10 minutes after I shut the power switch off, I don't know if that's normal.

Specs, if you need it:

Seagate Barracuda 1TB 7200RPM
HyperX Fury DDR3 16GB Black 1600MHz DDR3
Intel Core i5-4460
MSI GeForce GTX 960 Gaming 2GB Twin Frozr V
Cooler Master 650W PSU, 80 Plus Bronze, Modular

Comment: Sounds like a bad PSU. It's buzzing even after you power off the computer? What about if you unplug it?

Comment: I had a Compaq, I think that had the PSU go bad. The only thing to do was get a new one and replace it. The Cooler Master 650W PSU likely has nothing User Serviceable inside, so check with who you bought it from to see if they will give you an exchange. You may also want to consider more W... You have a lot of high performance, high demand hardware in that box.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described it is most likely your PSU that has gone bad. You can do a simple test to check your PSU at your own risk. All you need is a paperclip that you will need to reshape.

**WARNING: Do not try to insert the paperclip while the power cord or switch is turned on and do not touch the paperclip while the power is on.**

1. Remove your power supply from the chassis/case and unplug the power cord. Flip it off ("0" position).
2. On the 24-pin connector find the only green (power signal) wire. Also notice the black (ground) wires around it.
3. Insert one end of the paperclip into green wire and the other into one of the black wire.
4. Plug in the power cord and flip the switch on your power supply.

This will send a power signal to the PSU. If the fan does not spin, the PSU is the culprit.

Comment: I'd add this is a test for *definate* badness, rather than proper functioning. Its also reasonably safe, by which I mean you can do dumber, more dangerous things with a PSU, like open it up.

Comment: You should also disconnect your hard drive when testing PSUs. Sometimes you happen to switch it on and off again dozens of times, and hard drives don't really like this. Also, some PSUs aren't happy with starting up "empty", with nothing connected to it. You may connect a small load on it, like a fan, if you can.

Comment: If you have a voltmeter, use that to measure the voltage across the rails.